# jquery form validator does not with ajax, I can get jquery to validate without ajax and vic versa

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is my code that is not working with the jquery validator and ajax. This code does validate and the `serialize()` function seems to work because in the browser I see the data but it is not reaching my success because it just refreshed the page and the data does not go into mysql. Been reading all sorts of threads and nothing is working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
    //validate contact form
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form_contact").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name"
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: "Please enter your last name"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address."
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Please enter a message."
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var d = $("#form_contact").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/assets/php/index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //dataType: 'text',
                    data: d,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //$('#form_contact').hide();
                        $("#thanks").text("Thank you for your message. I will get back to you shortly.");
                        $("#form_contact")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
                        return false;
                    }
                }):
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Here is my html as well because when I change the submit button to input it works to validate and when I change it to span it works for ajax so something strange here to. <span id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</span>       and  <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

Comment: I would suggest adding some error handling to your AJAX call. Also you have a colon : after your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) as,

```
submitHandler: function(ev, form) { //I dont know what this form object is doing here, add event object, ev.
                var d = $("#form_contact").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/assets/php/index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //dataType: 'text',
                    data: d,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //$('#form_contact').hide();
                        $("#thanks").text("Thank you for your message. I will get back to you shortly.");
                        $("#form_contact")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
                        //return false; <-- commented it out.
                    }
                })
              //: <-- commented this colon character
             ev.preventDefault(); //add it here to prevent the form from submitting
            }
```

Please read out the comments for further clarification and I don't think you need that other `return false` either. I've already removed one, chaeck the answer code.

Comment: It is still refreshing and the data is not going into myphpadmin

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define error handler in `$.ajax` call. And I think it refreshes cause return false is only in success handler but it is not called if there is some error. So define the error handler with `console.log(data)`.

Comment: This would be best as a comment. If you can not comment yet, post actual answers until you can! Also best to post sample code with answers. See [posting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Yes it has no sense. But my ansver looks like your and I tryed to repair that peace of code(unsuccessfully).

Comment: How do I define the error handler? is it error: function(data){ console.log(data)}? not getting an error back?

Comment: Error handler is part of `$.ajax` settings object like success handler. Look at the documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I get this error in the console log : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on this line firstname:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2 --here is where the error is
                        },

Comment: That {required ....} object is response data object? It seems there is a syntax error( missing comma, ...???).